# Missing GStreamer plugins h264parse, and avdec_eac3

Tags: gstreamer, crossover

I attempted to install LabVIEW Community into a Crossover 64 bit Windows 10 bottle. At first there were many errors that indicated missing libraries. I installed them, and these errors no longer appear after an installation attempt. But I still have these remaining missing plugin errors:

```
[MissingGStreamer1Bad2]
"Title"="The gst-plugins-bad 32-bit GStreamer plugins appear to be missing h264parse"

[MissingGStreamer1Libav]
"Title"="The gst-libav 32-bit GStreamer plugins appear to be missing avdec_eac3"
```

I do not know what to do about them. How are these missing plugins installed?

Crossover Version: 21.0.0

OS: 64 bit Ubuntu 20.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Installing the 32-bit version libraries removed this issue for me (reported also by crossover office 365 setup on Ubuntu 20.04):

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav:i386 \
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386
```